# How to automatically assign label.y position in stat_compare_means() under facet with free scale (different y-height)

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse, ggpubr

I have the following dataframe:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggpubr)
    
    dat <- structure(list(genes = c("Gene1", "Gene2", "Gene1", "Gene1", 
"Gene1", "Gene1", "Gene1", "Gene1", "Gene2", "Gene2", "Gene2", 
"Gene2", "Gene2", "Gene1", "Gene2", "Gene1", "Gene2", "Gene1", 
"Gene1", "Gene1", "Gene2", "Gene1", "Gene1", "Gene1", "Gene1", 
"Gene2", "Gene2", "Gene2", "Gene2", "Gene1", "Gene1", "Gene1", 
"Gene1", "Gene2", "Gene2", "Gene1", "Gene2", "Gene2", "Gene1", 
"Gene2", "Gene1", "Gene2", "Gene1", "Gene2", "Gene1", "Gene2", 
"Gene1", "Gene2", "Gene2", "Gene1", "Gene1", "Gene2", "Gene2", 
"Gene1", "Gene2", "Gene2", "Gene2", "Gene2", "Gene1", "Gene1", 
"Gene1", "Gene2", "Gene2", "Gene1", "Gene1", "Gene1", "Gene1", 
"Gene2", "Gene1", "Gene1", "Gene2", "Gene1", "Gene2", "Gene1", 
"Gene2", "Gene1", "Gene2", "Gene1", "Gene2", "Gene2", "Gene1", 
"Gene2", "Gene2", "Gene2", "Gene1", "Gene1", "Gene2", "Gene1", 
"Gene2", "Gene1", "Gene1", "Gene2", "Gene1", "Gene2", "Gene2", 
"Gene2", "Gene2", "Gene2", "Gene1", "Gene2", "Gene1", "Gene1", 
"Gene2", "Gene2", "Gene2", "Gene1", "Gene1", "Gene2", "Gene1", 
"Gene2", "Gene1", "Gene2", "Gene2", "Gene1", "Gene2", "Gene2", 
"Gene2", "Gene1", "Gene1", "Gene1", "Gene2", "Gene1", "Gene2", 
"Gene2", "Gene2", "Gene1", "Gene2", "Gene1", "Gene2", "Gene2", 
"Gene2", "Gene1", "Gene2", "Gene1", "Gene1", "Gene1", "Gene2", 
"Gene1", "Gene1", "Gene1", "Gene2", "Gene2", "Gene2", "Gene2", 
"Gene2", "Gene1", "Gene2", "Gene2", "Gene1", "Gene2", "Gene1", 
"Gene2", "Gene2", "Gene2", "Gene1", "Gene1", "Gene2", "Gene1", 
"Gene2", "Gene1", "Gene2", "Gene2", "Gene2", "Gene2", "Gene2", 
"Gene2", "Gene2", "Gene2", "Gene1", "Gene2", "Gene2", "Gene1", 
"Gene2", "Gene2", "Gene2", "Gene1", "Gene1", "Gene1", "Gene2", 
"Gene2", "Gene2", "Gene1", "Gene2", "Gene1", "Gene1", "Gene1", 
"Gene1", "Gene2", "Gene2", "Gene2", "Gene1", "Gene1", "Gene1", 
"Gene2", "Gene1", "Gene2", "Gene1", "Gene1", "Gene1", "Gene1", 
"Gene2", "Gene2", "Gene2", "Gene1", "Gene1", "Gene1", "Gene2", 
"Gene1", "Gene2", "Gene1", "Gene1", "Gene1", "Gene2", "Gene2", 
"Gene1", "Gene2", "Gene2", "Gene2", "Gene2", "Gene2", "Gene1", 
"Gene1", "Gene1", "Gene2", "Gene1", "Gene1", "Gene2", "Gene1", 
"Gene2", "Gene2", "Gene1", "Gene1", "Gene1", "Gene2", "Gene1", 
"Gene2", "Gene2", "Gene1", "Gene1", "Gene2", "Gene2", "Gene1", 
"Gene2", "Gene1", "Gene2", "Gene2", "Gene1", "Gene2", "Gene1", 
"Gene2", "Gene1", "Gene1", "Gene2", "Gene2", "Gene1", "Gene2", 
"Gene2", "Gene1", "Gene2", "Gene1", "Gene1", "Gene1", "Gene2", 
"Gene1", "Gene1", "Gene1", "Gene1", "Gene2", "Gene1", "Gene2", 
"Gene2", "Gene2", "Gene2", "Gene2", "Gene1", "Gene1", "Gene1", 
"Gene1", "Gene2", "Gene1", "Gene1", "Gene1", "Gene2", "Gene2", 
"Gene1", "Gene1", "Gene2", "Gene1", "Gene1", "Gene1", "Gene1", 
"Gene1", "Gene1", "Gene1", "Gene1", "Gene1", "Gene1", "Gene2", 
"Gene1", "Gene1", "Gene1", "Gene2", "Gene1", "Gene2", "Gene2", 
"Gene1", "Gene1", "Gene2", "Gene1", "Gene1", "Gene1", "Gene1", 
"Gene2", "Gene1", "Gene2", "Gene2", "Gene2", "Gene2", "Gene1", 
"Gene2", "Gene2", "Gene1", "Gene2", "Gene2", "Gene1", "Gene2", 
"Gene1", "Gene2", "Gene2", "Gene2", "Gene1", "Gene2", "Gene2", 
"Gene1", "Gene1", "Gene2", "Gene1", "Gene1", "Gene2", "Gene2", 
"Gene2", "Gene1", "Gene1", "Gene2", "Gene1", "Gene2", "Gene2", 
"Gene2", "Gene1", "Gene2", "Gene2", "Gene2", "Gene2", "Gene1", 
"Gene2", "Gene2", "Gene2", "Gene2", "Gene2", "Gene1", "Gene2", 
"Gene1", "Gene2", "Gene1", "Gene1", "Gene1", "Gene2", "Gene1", 
"Gene2", "Gene2", "Gene1", "Gene2", "Gene2", "Gene1", "Gene1", 
"Gene2", "Gene1", "Gene2", "Gene1", "Gene1", "Gene1", "Gene2", 
"Gene2", "Gene2", "Gene1", "Gene1", "Gene1", "Gene2", "Gene2", 
"Gene1", "Gene1", "Gene1", "Gene1", "Gene1", "Gene2", "Gene2", 
"Gene2", "Gene2", "Gene2", "Gene1", "Gene2", "Gene2", "Gene1", 
"Gene1", "Gene1", "Gene1", "Gene2", "Gene2", "Gene1", "Gene1", 
"Gene1", "Gene1", "Gene1", "Gene1", "Gene2", "Gene1", "Gene1", 
"Gene1", "Gene1", "Gene1", "Gene1", "Gene1", "Gene2", "Gene1", 
"Gene1", "Gene2", "Gene1", "Gene2", "Gene1", "Gene2", "Gene2", 
"Gene1", "Gene1", "Gene1", "Gene1", "Gene1", "Gene2", "Gene2", 
"Gene2", "Gene2", "Gene2", "Gene1", "Gene2", "Gene1", "Gene2", 
"Gene1", "Gene2", "Gene1", "Gene1", "Gene1", "Gene1", "Gene1", 
"Gene1", "Gene1", "Gene1", "Gene1", "Gene1", "Gene1", "Gene1", 
"Gene1", "Gene1", "Gene2", "Gene2", "Gene1", "Gene1", "Gene1", 
"Gene2", "Gene2", "Gene2", "Gene1", "Gene1", "Gene1", "Gene2", 
"Gene1", "Gene1", "Gene1", "Gene2", "Gene1", "Gene2", "Gene2", 
"Gene2", "Gene2", "Gene1", "Gene1", "Gene2", "Gene2", "Gene2", 
"Gene2", "Gene1", "Gene2", "Gene2", "Gene2", "Gene1", "Gene1", 
"Gene2", "Gene1", "Gene2", "Gene1", "Gene2", "Gene2", "Gene1", 
"Gene1", "Gene2", "Gene2", "Gene2", "Gene2", "Gene1", "Gene2", 
"Gene2", "Gene2", "Gene2", "Gene1", "Gene2", "Gene2", "Gene2", 
"Gene2", "Gene1", "Gene1", "Gene1", "Gene1", "Gene2", "Gene2", 
"Gene1", "Gene2", "Gene1", "Gene2", "Gene2", "Gene1", "Gene2", 
"Gene1", "Gene2", "Gene1", "Gene2", "Gene2", "Gene2", "Gene2", 
"Gene2", "Gene1", "Gene2", "Gene1", "Gene1", "Gene2", "Gene2", 
"Gene2", "Gene2", "Gene1", "Gene1", "Gene1", "Gene2", "Gene1", 
"Gene2", "Gene1", "Gene2", "Gene2", "Gene2", "Gene2", "Gene2", 
"Gene2", "Gene2", "Gene2", "Gene2", "Gene2", "Gene1", "Gene2", 
"Gene2", "Gene1", "Gene1", "Gene1", "Gene2", "Gene1", "Gene1", 
"Gene2", "Gene1", "Gene2", "Gene2", "Gene1", "Gene1", "Gene1", 
"Gene1", "Gene1", "Gene1", "Gene1", "Gene1", "Gene1", "Gene1", 
"Gene2", "Gene2", "Gene1", "Gene1", "Gene1", "Gene1", "Gene1", 
"Gene1", "Gene1", "Gene2", "Gene1", "Gene1", "Gene1", "Gene1", 
"Gene1", "Gene1", "Gene2", "Gene2", "Gene1", "Gene2", "Gene2", 
"Gene1", "Gene2", "Gene2", "Gene2", "Gene2", "Gene2", "Gene2", 
"Gene2", "Gene1", "Gene1", "Gene1", "Gene1", "Gene1", "Gene2", 
"Gene1", "Gene2", "Gene2", "Gene2", "Gene2", "Gene1", "Gene2", 
"Gene1", "Gene1", "Gene1", "Gene1", "Gene2", "Gene2", "Gene2", 
"Gene1", "Gene1", "Gene1", "Gene1", "Gene2", "Gene2", "Gene2", 
"Gene2", "Gene1", "Gene2", "Gene1", "Gene1", "Gene2", "Gene1", 
"Gene1", "Gene2", "Gene2", "Gene2", "Gene1", "Gene1", "Gene2", 
"Gene1", "Gene1", "Gene1", "Gene1", "Gene2", "Gene2", "Gene1", 
"Gene1", "Gene1", "Gene1", "Gene2", "Gene1", "Gene1", "Gene1", 
"Gene1", "Gene1", "Gene1", "Gene1", "Gene2", "Gene1", "Gene1", 
"Gene2", "Gene1", "Gene1", "Gene2", "Gene2", "Gene1", "Gene1", 
"Gene2", "Gene2", "Gene1", "Gene2", "Gene1", "Gene1", "Gene2", 
"Gene1", "Gene2", "Gene2", "Gene1", "Gene2", "Gene2", "Gene2", 
"Gene2", "Gene2", "Gene1", "Gene1", "Gene1", "Gene1", "Gene1", 
"Gene2", "Gene1", "Gene1", "Gene2", "Gene1", "Gene2", "Gene2", 
"Gene1", "Gene2", "Gene1", "Gene2", "Gene1", "Gene1", "Gene1", 
"Gene1", "Gene1", "Gene1", "Gene2", "Gene2", "Gene2", "Gene2", 
"Gene1", "Gene2", "Gene2", "Gene2", "Gene1", "Gene1", "Gene1"
), gexp = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 
0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 3, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 1, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 
0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 2, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0), GROUP = c("Bc_Lin+", "Hd_Lin-", "Hd_Lin+", "Hd_Lin+", "Tl_Lin-", 
"Bc_Lin-", "Hd_Lin-", "Bc_Lin-", "Ab_Lin-", "Bc_Lin+", "Hd_Lin-", 
"Bc_Lin+", "Ab_Lin+", "Tl_Lin+", "Bc_Lin-", "Ab_Lin-", "Hd_Lin-", 
"Bc_Lin-", "Bc_Lin+", "Hd_Lin+", "Bc_Lin+", "Ab_Lin-", "Bc_Lin+", 
"Bc_Lin-", "Bc_Lin+", "Hd_Lin-", "Bc_Lin+", "Bc_Lin+", "Tl_Lin+", 
"Hd_Lin-", "Ab_Lin+", "Hd_Lin+", "Bc_Lin-", "Hd_Lin-", "Ab_Lin+", 
"Ab_Lin+", "Hd_Lin-", "Hd_Lin-", "Bc_Lin+", "Ab_Lin-", "Hd_Lin+", 
"Bc_Lin+", "Ab_Lin+", "Tl_Lin+", "Bc_Lin-", "Hd_Lin+", "Hd_Lin-", 
"Ab_Lin-", "Ab_Lin-", "Ab_Lin-", "Hd_Lin-", "Ab_Lin-", "Bc_Lin-", 
"Hd_Lin+", "Tl_Lin+", "Bc_Lin+", "Bc_Lin-", "Ab_Lin-", "Tl_Lin+", 
"Ab_Lin-", "Ab_Lin+", "Hd_Lin+", "Hd_Lin+", "Ab_Lin-", "Tl_Lin+", 
"Bc_Lin+", "Hd_Lin+", "Ab_Lin-", "Bc_Lin-", "Bc_Lin-", "Ab_Lin+", 
"Bc_Lin+", "Ab_Lin-", "Bc_Lin-", "Bc_Lin+", "Hd_Lin+", "Bc_Lin+", 
"Hd_Lin+", "Hd_Lin+", "Bc_Lin-", "Hd_Lin-", "Bc_Lin-", "Tl_Lin+", 
"Hd_Lin+", "Bc_Lin-", "Ab_Lin-", "Bc_Lin-", "Tl_Lin+", "Bc_Lin+", 
"Tl_Lin+", "Hd_Lin+", "Tl_Lin+", "Hd_Lin-", "Hd_Lin-", "Hd_Lin+", 
"Tl_Lin+", "Bc_Lin-", "Hd_Lin-", "Ab_Lin+", "Hd_Lin-", "Hd_Lin+", 
"Bc_Lin+", "Tl_Lin+", "Tl_Lin+", "Ab_Lin-", "Ab_Lin+", "Tl_Lin+", 
"Tl_Lin+", "Ab_Lin-", "Ab_Lin-", "Ab_Lin-", "Bc_Lin+", "Hd_Lin+", 
"Ab_Lin-", "Ab_Lin+", "Hd_Lin-", "Bc_Lin-", "Ab_Lin+", "Hd_Lin+", 
"Bc_Lin-", "Tl_Lin+", "Hd_Lin-", "Hd_Lin+", "Ab_Lin-", "Ab_Lin-", 
"Hd_Lin-", "Hd_Lin-", "Bc_Lin-", "Ab_Lin+", "Hd_Lin-", "Hd_Lin-", 
"Ab_Lin-", "Hd_Lin+", "Hd_Lin-", "Ab_Lin-", "Ab_Lin-", "Hd_Lin-", 
"Bc_Lin-", "Hd_Lin-", "Ab_Lin+", "Bc_Lin-", "Tl_Lin-", "Bc_Lin+", 
"Bc_Lin+", "Ab_Lin+", "Hd_Lin-", "Ab_Lin-", "Tl_Lin-", "Bc_Lin-", 
"Bc_Lin-", "Ab_Lin-", "Hd_Lin+", "Hd_Lin+", "Bc_Lin-", "Hd_Lin-", 
"Bc_Lin-", "Bc_Lin+", "Bc_Lin+", "Bc_Lin+", "Ab_Lin+", "Bc_Lin-", 
"Ab_Lin-", "Ab_Lin-", "Tl_Lin+", "Ab_Lin+", "Ab_Lin-", "Ab_Lin+", 
"Hd_Lin+", "Ab_Lin+", "Bc_Lin+", "Tl_Lin+", "Bc_Lin+", "Ab_Lin+", 
"Hd_Lin+", "Ab_Lin-", "Tl_Lin+", "Hd_Lin-", "Bc_Lin-", "Hd_Lin-", 
"Hd_Lin-", "Bc_Lin+", "Ab_Lin+", "Ab_Lin+", "Tl_Lin+", "Ab_Lin-", 
"Hd_Lin-", "Ab_Lin+", "Ab_Lin+", "Bc_Lin+", "Bc_Lin+", "Ab_Lin+", 
"Tl_Lin+", "Tl_Lin+", "Ab_Lin+", "Hd_Lin+", "Bc_Lin-", "Hd_Lin+", 
"Ab_Lin+", "Hd_Lin-", "Ab_Lin-", "Hd_Lin-", "Ab_Lin+", "Tl_Lin+", 
"Hd_Lin-", "Bc_Lin-", "Tl_Lin+", "Bc_Lin-", "Ab_Lin-", "Hd_Lin+", 
"Tl_Lin+", "Hd_Lin+", "Ab_Lin-", "Ab_Lin+", "Ab_Lin-", "Bc_Lin-", 
"Hd_Lin+", "Hd_Lin-", "Hd_Lin+", "Ab_Lin-", "Ab_Lin-", "Ab_Lin-", 
"Hd_Lin+", "Bc_Lin+", "Hd_Lin+", "Hd_Lin+", "Ab_Lin-", "Hd_Lin+", 
"Tl_Lin+", "Hd_Lin+", "Hd_Lin+", "Hd_Lin-", "Tl_Lin+", "Hd_Lin+", 
"Hd_Lin-", "Ab_Lin-", "Bc_Lin+", "Bc_Lin+", "Tl_Lin+", "Ab_Lin+", 
"Bc_Lin+", "Hd_Lin-", "Bc_Lin-", "Ab_Lin+", "Tl_Lin+", "Bc_Lin+", 
"Hd_Lin+", "Tl_Lin-", "Tl_Lin+", "Ab_Lin-", "Bc_Lin+", "Ab_Lin+", 
"Ab_Lin-", "Ab_Lin-", "Ab_Lin+", "Hd_Lin+", "Hd_Lin-", "Ab_Lin-", 
"Tl_Lin+", "Bc_Lin-", "Bc_Lin-", "Bc_Lin-", "Bc_Lin+", "Bc_Lin+", 
"Ab_Lin-", "Tl_Lin+", "Ab_Lin-", "Bc_Lin-", "Ab_Lin-", "Ab_Lin-", 
"Ab_Lin+", "Bc_Lin-", "Ab_Lin+", "Ab_Lin-", "Ab_Lin+", "Tl_Lin-", 
"Bc_Lin+", "Bc_Lin+", "Ab_Lin+", "Tl_Lin-", "Tl_Lin+", "Ab_Lin-", 
"Bc_Lin+", "Bc_Lin-", "Bc_Lin+", "Ab_Lin-", "Ab_Lin+", "Tl_Lin+", 
"Tl_Lin+", "Ab_Lin+", "Bc_Lin-", "Ab_Lin-", "Bc_Lin-", "Tl_Lin+", 
"Tl_Lin-", "Tl_Lin+", "Hd_Lin-", "Hd_Lin+", "Ab_Lin+", "Hd_Lin-", 
"Bc_Lin-", "Bc_Lin-", "Bc_Lin+", "Bc_Lin-", "Bc_Lin+", "Ab_Lin+", 
"Tl_Lin-", "Bc_Lin-", "Hd_Lin+", "Bc_Lin+", "Ab_Lin-", "Ab_Lin-", 
"Ab_Lin-", "Ab_Lin+", "Hd_Lin+", "Ab_Lin-", "Bc_Lin+", "Ab_Lin+", 
"Bc_Lin-", "Hd_Lin+", "Bc_Lin+", "Tl_Lin+", "Hd_Lin+", "Bc_Lin+", 
"Bc_Lin-", "Ab_Lin-", "Tl_Lin+", "Hd_Lin-", "Bc_Lin-", "Bc_Lin-", 
"Hd_Lin-", "Bc_Lin-", "Tl_Lin+", "Ab_Lin-", "Hd_Lin-", "Hd_Lin+", 
"Ab_Lin+", "Hd_Lin+", "Tl_Lin-", "Bc_Lin-", "Bc_Lin-", "Ab_Lin+", 
"Bc_Lin+", "Tl_Lin-", "Tl_Lin+", "Bc_Lin-", "Bc_Lin+", "Hd_Lin+", 
"Bc_Lin+", "Ab_Lin+", "Bc_Lin+", "Bc_Lin-", "Tl_Lin+", "Bc_Lin-", 
"Ab_Lin-", "Bc_Lin-", "Bc_Lin+", "Ab_Lin-", "Hd_Lin+", "Bc_Lin+", 
"Hd_Lin-", "Tl_Lin+", "Tl_Lin+", "Ab_Lin+", "Ab_Lin-", "Ab_Lin+", 
"Bc_Lin+", "Hd_Lin-", "Ab_Lin-", "Tl_Lin-", "Hd_Lin+", "Tl_Lin+", 
"Bc_Lin+", "Hd_Lin+", "Hd_Lin-", "Ab_Lin-", "Bc_Lin+", "Bc_Lin-", 
"Ab_Lin-", "Hd_Lin-", "Hd_Lin-", "Hd_Lin-", "Bc_Lin+", "Ab_Lin+", 
"Bc_Lin+", "Bc_Lin+", "Hd_Lin+", "Bc_Lin+", "Ab_Lin+", "Bc_Lin+", 
"Hd_Lin+", "Bc_Lin+", "Tl_Lin+", "Bc_Lin-", "Tl_Lin+", "Hd_Lin-", 
"Tl_Lin+", "Bc_Lin+", "Bc_Lin+", "Bc_Lin-", "Tl_Lin-", "Bc_Lin-", 
"Tl_Lin+", "Bc_Lin+", "Hd_Lin-", "Ab_Lin+", "Ab_Lin-", "Ab_Lin-", 
"Ab_Lin-", "Ab_Lin-", "Tl_Lin-", "Bc_Lin-", "Ab_Lin+", "Ab_Lin-", 
"Tl_Lin+", "Ab_Lin+", "Ab_Lin-", "Hd_Lin+", "Ab_Lin+", "Bc_Lin-", 
"Bc_Lin+", "Bc_Lin-", "Ab_Lin-", "Tl_Lin+", "Hd_Lin-", "Ab_Lin-", 
"Ab_Lin-", "Ab_Lin+", "Bc_Lin+", "Hd_Lin+", "Tl_Lin+", "Bc_Lin-", 
"Ab_Lin-", "Bc_Lin+", "Tl_Lin+", "Bc_Lin-", "Bc_Lin+", "Ab_Lin+", 
"Ab_Lin-", "Ab_Lin-", "Bc_Lin+", "Bc_Lin-", "Ab_Lin-", "Hd_Lin+", 
"Tl_Lin-", "Hd_Lin+", "Hd_Lin-", "Bc_Lin+", "Ab_Lin+", "Hd_Lin-", 
"Tl_Lin+", "Ab_Lin-", "Bc_Lin+", "Ab_Lin-", "Tl_Lin+", "Bc_Lin-", 
"Bc_Lin-", "Ab_Lin-", "Tl_Lin-", "Bc_Lin+", "Hd_Lin+", "Bc_Lin+", 
"Bc_Lin-", "Hd_Lin+", "Bc_Lin+", "Tl_Lin+", "Ab_Lin+", "Ab_Lin+", 
"Hd_Lin+", "Ab_Lin-", "Bc_Lin+", "Hd_Lin-", "Hd_Lin+", "Ab_Lin-", 
"Hd_Lin-", "Tl_Lin+", "Tl_Lin+", "Hd_Lin-", "Hd_Lin+", "Bc_Lin+", 
"Hd_Lin-", "Bc_Lin-", "Bc_Lin+", "Bc_Lin-", "Bc_Lin-", "Bc_Lin-", 
"Tl_Lin+", "Bc_Lin+", "Ab_Lin-", "Ab_Lin+", "Bc_Lin+", "Bc_Lin+", 
"Tl_Lin+", "Ab_Lin+", "Ab_Lin+", "Hd_Lin-", "Bc_Lin+", "Hd_Lin+", 
"Bc_Lin-", "Ab_Lin+", "Hd_Lin-", "Hd_Lin-", "Tl_Lin+", "Ab_Lin+", 
"Bc_Lin+", "Tl_Lin-", "Bc_Lin-", "Bc_Lin-", "Hd_Lin+", "Ab_Lin-", 
"Bc_Lin+", "Ab_Lin-", "Tl_Lin+", "Ab_Lin+", "Bc_Lin-", "Hd_Lin+", 
"Ab_Lin+", "Tl_Lin+", "Hd_Lin-", "Ab_Lin-", "Bc_Lin+", "Bc_Lin+", 
"Hd_Lin+", "Bc_Lin+", "Tl_Lin+", "Ab_Lin+", "Tl_Lin+", "Ab_Lin+", 
"Bc_Lin-", "Hd_Lin-", "Hd_Lin+", "Hd_Lin-", "Bc_Lin-", "Ab_Lin+", 
"Ab_Lin-", "Hd_Lin+", "Tl_Lin+", "Ab_Lin+", "Ab_Lin+", "Bc_Lin+", 
"Bc_Lin-", "Ab_Lin+", "Ab_Lin-", "Tl_Lin+", "Bc_Lin-", "Bc_Lin-", 
"Tl_Lin+", "Ab_Lin-", "Bc_Lin+", "Hd_Lin+", "Bc_Lin+", "Bc_Lin-", 
"Bc_Lin-", "Tl_Lin+", "Bc_Lin+", "Hd_Lin-", "Bc_Lin+", "Ab_Lin+", 
"Bc_Lin-", "Bc_Lin-", "Hd_Lin-", "Ab_Lin-", "Ab_Lin+", "Bc_Lin-", 
"Bc_Lin+", "Tl_Lin+", "Ab_Lin-", "Ab_Lin+", "Ab_Lin-", "Ab_Lin+", 
"Hd_Lin+", "Tl_Lin+", "Hd_Lin-", "Tl_Lin+", "Ab_Lin-", "Hd_Lin+", 
"Bc_Lin-", "Ab_Lin+", "Hd_Lin+", "Ab_Lin+", "Ab_Lin+", "Ab_Lin+", 
"Ab_Lin-", "Ab_Lin+", "Bc_Lin-", "Hd_Lin+", "Bc_Lin-", "Hd_Lin+", 
"Ab_Lin+", "Bc_Lin+", "Tl_Lin-", "Tl_Lin-", "Hd_Lin-", "Bc_Lin-", 
"Ab_Lin-", "Hd_Lin+", "Hd_Lin+", "Tl_Lin+", "Hd_Lin-", "Ab_Lin-", 
"Bc_Lin-", "Tl_Lin+", "Bc_Lin+", "Hd_Lin-", "Ab_Lin+", "Bc_Lin-", 
"Tl_Lin-", "Hd_Lin+", "Tl_Lin+", "Bc_Lin+", "Ab_Lin+", "Tl_Lin+", 
"Ab_Lin+", "Bc_Lin-", "Bc_Lin-", "Hd_Lin-", "Ab_Lin+", "Bc_Lin-", 
"Bc_Lin-", "Hd_Lin+", "Hd_Lin+", "Ab_Lin-", "Tl_Lin-", "Tl_Lin+", 
"Ab_Lin+", "Tl_Lin+", "Hd_Lin+", "Hd_Lin+", "Hd_Lin-", "Hd_Lin+", 
"Hd_Lin-", "Bc_Lin+", "Ab_Lin+", "Bc_Lin+", "Ab_Lin+", "Tl_Lin+", 
"Bc_Lin-", "Hd_Lin+", "Ab_Lin+", "Bc_Lin-", "Bc_Lin-", "Hd_Lin+", 
"Ab_Lin-", "Hd_Lin+", "Tl_Lin-", "Ab_Lin+", "Bc_Lin+", "Bc_Lin-", 
"Ab_Lin+", "Ab_Lin+", "Hd_Lin+", "Hd_Lin+", "Bc_Lin+", "Bc_Lin-", 
"Ab_Lin+", "Hd_Lin-", "Tl_Lin+", "Bc_Lin+", "Tl_Lin-", "Tl_Lin-", 
"Hd_Lin-", "Bc_Lin-", "Bc_Lin+", "Tl_Lin-", "Hd_Lin+", "Hd_Lin-", 
"Tl_Lin+", "Hd_Lin-", "Bc_Lin+", "Hd_Lin+", "Hd_Lin+", "Bc_Lin+", 
"Ab_Lin-", "Ab_Lin+", "Ab_Lin-", "Hd_Lin-", "Ab_Lin-", "Tl_Lin+", 
"Bc_Lin+", "Bc_Lin-", "Hd_Lin+", "Bc_Lin-", "Ab_Lin+", "Hd_Lin+", 
"Bc_Lin-", "Ab_Lin+", "Bc_Lin-", "Tl_Lin-", "Ab_Lin+", "Hd_Lin-", 
"Bc_Lin+", "Ab_Lin-", "Hd_Lin+", "Hd_Lin+", "Bc_Lin+", "Ab_Lin+", 
"Bc_Lin-", "Ab_Lin-", "Tl_Lin+", "Ab_Lin-", "Bc_Lin-", "Tl_Lin+", 
"Ab_Lin-", "Hd_Lin-", "Ab_Lin+", "Tl_Lin-", "Tl_Lin+", "Bc_Lin+", 
"Bc_Lin-", "Hd_Lin+", "Bc_Lin-", "Ab_Lin-", "Bc_Lin-", "Ab_Lin-", 
"Hd_Lin+", "Ab_Lin-", "Hd_Lin-", "Ab_Lin-", "Bc_Lin+", "Ab_Lin+", 
"Bc_Lin-", "Bc_Lin-", "Ab_Lin-", "Hd_Lin+", "Ab_Lin+", "Hd_Lin-", 
"Ab_Lin+", "Ab_Lin+", "Hd_Lin+", "Bc_Lin-", "Bc_Lin-", "Bc_Lin-", 
"Ab_Lin-")), row.names = c(NA, -732L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))
```

What I want is to perform statistical comparison between GROUP column.
Here is the code I have

```
sort_order <-  c("Hd_Lin+", "Hd_Lin-", 
                 "Ab_Lin+", "Ab_Lin-", 
                 "Bc_Lin+", "Bc_Lin-", 
                 "Tl_Lin+", "Tl_Lin-")

dat <- dat %>% 
       mutate(GROUP = factor(GROUP, levels = sort_order))
       my_comparison <- list(
      c("Hd_Lin+", "Hd_Lin-"), 
      c("Ab_Lin+", "Ab_Lin-"), 
      c("Bc_Lin+", "Bc_Lin-"), 
      c("Tl_Lin+", "Tl_Lin-"))
    
    
    ggpubr::ggbarplot(dat, x = "GROUP", y = "gexp", add = "mean_se", facet.by = "genes", 
                      scales = "free") + 
      stat_compare_means(aes(label = ..p.signif..),
             
                         label.y = c(seq( 0.456, by = 0, length.out = 4),seq( 0.125, by = 0, length.out = 4)),
                         tip.length = 0, vjust = 0.5,
                         method = "t.test", comparisons = my_comparison) + 
      theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1, vjust = 0.5, size = 12))  + 
      xlab("")
```

As you notice in the plot below the stat test line is the same for both Gene1 and Gene2.

[image]

How can I automatically adjust it for different facet of free y-scale?

This line doesn't seem to work:

```
 label.y = c(seq( 0.456, by = 0, length.out = 4),seq( 0.125, by = 0, length.out = 4))
```

We can do a pre-calculation that the max mean of each gene is in this range: `0.4561404 0.1250000`.

Comment: I don't think that's possible just with ggpubr - too high level function. Use ggplot lower level instead, it's really not that much more difficult, and way more versatile. and create extra data frames with the summary values for each facet group, as you were probably already considering.

Comment: Also could you kindly elaborate how you are calculating those values? It might be just me, but you are using geom_col `geom_bar(stat = "identity")` on a count variable, and I don't understand how to get to those decimal values that you are displaying.

Comment: I believe this article should fix your issues https://www.datanovia.com/en/blog/add-p-values-to-ggplot-facets-with-different-scales/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. It's applicable to any number of genes. No hard coding:

```
library(rstatix)
sort_order <- c(
  "Hd_Lin+", "Hd_Lin-",
  "Ab_Lin+", "Ab_Lin-",
  "Bc_Lin+", "Bc_Lin-",
  "Tl_Lin+", "Tl_Lin-"
)


my_comparisons <- list(
  c("Hd_Lin+", "Hd_Lin-"),
  c("Ab_Lin+", "Ab_Lin-"),
  c("Bc_Lin+", "Bc_Lin-"),
  c("Tl_Lin+", "Tl_Lin-")
)

dat <- dat %>% 
  mutate(GROUP = factor(GROUP, levels = sort_order))

stat.test <- dat %>% 
  group_by(genes) %>% 
  t_test(gexp ~ GROUP, p.adjust.method = "none") %>% 
  add_xy_position(x = "GROUP", fun = "mean_se", 
                scales = "free", comparisons = my_comparisons, step.increase = 0) %>% 
  mutate(p.adj.signif = if_else(p.adj.signif == "", "NS.", p.adj.signif)) 
    

p <- ggpubr::ggbarplot(dat, x = "GROUP", y = "gexp", add = "mean_se",
                  facet =  "genes", scales = "free"
                 ) +
  stat_pvalue_manual(stat.test, hide.ns = FALSE, tip.length = 0, bracket.nudge.y = 0.01) +
  # scale_y_continuous(expand = expansion(mult = c(0.05, 0.5))) +
  theme(strip.text.x = element_text(size = 20, colour = "black", face = "bold")) +
  theme(legend.position = "none") +
  xlab("") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1, vjust = 0.5))

p
```

It produces:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This could be one way to achieve your task:

**Resulting plot:**

[image]

**The code**

```
# your data

sort_order <-  c("Hd_Lin+", "Hd_Lin-", 
                 "Ab_Lin+", "Ab_Lin-", 
                 "Bc_Lin+", "Bc_Lin-", 
                 "Tl_Lin+", "Tl_Lin-")

dat <- dat %>% 
  mutate(GROUP = factor(GROUP, levels = sort_order))
my_comparison <- list(
  c("Hd_Lin+", "Hd_Lin-"), 
  c("Ab_Lin+", "Ab_Lin-"), 
  c("Bc_Lin+", "Bc_Lin-"), 
  c("Tl_Lin+", "Tl_Lin-"))


library(ggpubr)
library(tidyverse)

# data for Gene1
dat1 <- dat %>% 
  filter(genes=="Gene1")

# date for Gene2
dat2 <- dat %>% 
  filter(genes=="Gene2")

# plot p1
p1 <- ggpubr::ggbarplot(dat1, x = "GROUP", y = "gexp", add = "mean_se", facet.by = "genes", 
                  scales = "free") + 
  stat_compare_means(aes(label = ..p.signif..),
                     label.y = c(seq( 0.3, by = 0, length.out = 4)),
                     tip.length = 0, vjust = 0.5,
                     method = "t.test", comparisons = my_comparison) + 
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1, vjust = 0.5, size = 12))  + 
  xlab("") +
  coord_cartesian(ylim=c(0, 0.6)) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0,0.5,0.1), labels = seq(0.1,0.6,0.1))
  

# plot p2
p2 <- ggpubr::ggbarplot(dat2, x = "GROUP", y = "gexp", add = "mean_se", facet.by = "genes", 
                        scales = "free") + 
  stat_compare_means(aes(label = ..p.signif..),
                     label.y = c(seq( 0.6, by = 0, length.out = 4)),
                     tip.length = 0, vjust = 0.5,
                     method = "t.test", comparisons = my_comparison) + 
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1, vjust = 0.5, size = 12))  + 
  xlab("") +
  coord_cartesian(ylim=c(0, 0.6)) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0,0.5,0.1), labels = seq(0.1,0.6,0.1))

ggarrange(p1, p2, heights = c(4, 4), nrow = 1, align = "h")
```

**Explanation**

I tried to access label.y within facets, but failed. See here https://github.com/kassambara/ggpubr/issues/50.

Then I decided to apply a workaround: Here is the idea:

1. Create for each Gene a separate plot and facet it with it self by filtering `dat1`
   for `gene1` and `dat2` for `gene2`.
2. The challenge here was to adapt the `ylim`, finally I achieved this by this code

```
coord_cartesian(ylim=c(0, 0.6)) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0,0.5,0.1), labels = seq(0.1,0.6,0.1))
```

3. Now you can individually change the position of your `stat_compare_means` by changing `..c(seq(0.3` to `..c(seq(0.4` etc.
4. Finally you can combine both plots with `ggarrange` from `ggpubr` package

Comment: thanks. But I need to `facet_wrap()` the data. Because in reality the number of genes can be more than 2.